# D3 Multiline Chart with Tooltip Transition Issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have been using d3 to create a multiline chart with focus and context brushing. Everything is going well except on the transition the dots at the data points with the tooltips are moving to a completely wrong position. I can't  figure out what is causing this. Any help would be much appreciated. I attached the full code here and noted on the graph where I'm pretty sure the bug should be:

http://jsbin.com/osumaq/20/edit

When the button is clicked, a new json is passed to the graph to read.

The buggy block of code I think is this:

```
topicEnter.append("g").selectAll(".dot")
        .data(function (d) { return d.values }).enter().append("circle").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr("stroke", function (d) {
        return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name)
    })
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.probability);
    })
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "white").attr("fill-opacity", .5)
        .attr("stroke-width", 2).on("mouseover", function (d) {
        div.transition().duration(100).style("opacity", .9);
        div.html(this.parentNode.__data__.name + "<br/>" + d.probability).style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px").style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px").attr('r', 8);
        d3.select(this).attr('r', 8)
    }).on("mouseout", function (d) {
        div.transition().duration(100).style("opacity", 0)
        d3.select(this).attr('r', 5);
    });
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by tooltip ? Is it the window that appears when we hover on dots ? They seem fine. What I can see is that your dots are not moving while the lines are, and if I had to guess I would say your enter and update selections are mixed. If the dots are already on screen and you want to update their position (by calling your method `update`) you should have somthing along these lines :

```
// Bind your data
topicEnter.append("g").selectAll(".dot")
    .data(function (d) { return d.values })
// Enter selection
topicEnter.enter().append("circle").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)").attr("class", "dot");
// Update all the dots
topicEnter.attr("stroke", function (d) {
        return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name)
    })
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.probability);
    })
    [...]
```

Comment: Yeah, I meant the circles that contain the tooltips, sorry about that. That's the problem, and I'm trying to do what you said, but it's still not working. It appears that initially the new dots won't disappear and only the new (red) line has the circles in the correct place. Once you start playing around on the graph focus and context slider at the bottom, the old circles with now obsolete x axis go away, but new circles have the wrong y-axis, but at least at the correct x-axis.