# Create points on a D3 multiline graph

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add points to a line graph using d3 in this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

I was also trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262028/adding-point-and-value-to-line-chart-how-to-color-the-point-like-the-line?rq=1)

How do you get the points to look like this picture from the documentation?
http://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/line.png

The stroke of the circle should match the line color.

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
```

```
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var ranks = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, ranking: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });
```

```
  var rank = svg.selectAll(".rank")
      .data(ranks)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "rank");
    rank.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

```
var point = rank.append("g")
.attr("class", "line-point");

point.selectAll('circle')
.data(function(d){ return d.values})
.enter().append('circle')
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.ranking) })
.attr("r", 3.5)
.style("fill", "white")
.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Comment: There's a semicolon at the end of the line before the `.style()`.

Comment: Yes, that's the default.

Comment: You haven't actually posted the code you use to set the stroke colour...

Comment: Right, so `d.name` might be undefined for the circles because it's a subselection (`d.values`). I guess an easy thing to do would be to put the name in all of those data points as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
.style("stroke", function(d) { return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name); })
```

[See JSBin code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573771/adding-a-chart-legend-in-d3/13575785#13575785)
Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458007/d3-multiline-chart-with-tooltip-transition-issue)