# Adding circles to datapoints in d3 line plot

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a line chart where on each datapoint I have a circle marker. I have successfully managed to display three different lines. However when I try to add the circle marker only one shows up.  I am using the following code:

```
var data = [
                    {"date": "2009", "Bob": "1", "Alice" : "2", "Cecilia" : "3"},
                    {"date": "2010", "Bob": "2", "Alice" : "1", "Cecilia" : "3"},
                    {"date": "2011", "Bob": "3", "Alice" : "2", "Cecilia" : "1"},
                    {"date": "2012", "Bob": "4", "Alice" : "5", "Cecilia" : "1"},
                    {"date": "2013", "Bob": "3", "Alice" : "1", "Cecilia" : "2"},
                    {"date": "2014", "Bob": "1", "Alice" : "2", "Cecilia" : "3"}
                    ];

color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

var users = color.domain()
     .map(function(name) {
            return {
                name: name,
                values: data.map(function(d) {
                return {date: d.date, ranking: +d[name]};
                })
            };
        });
```

then to add the line I do the following:

```
 var user = svg.selectAll(".user")
 .data(users)
 .enter().append("g")
 .attr("class", "user");

 user.append("path")
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
 .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

then to add the circles I use the following code which results in only one circle appearing in the top left of my chart

```
        var nodes = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
        .data(users)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.values.date) + "," + y(d.values.ranking) + ")"; });
```

I am new to d3 and javascript and I would appreciate any help getting my code working.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693005/create-points-on-a-d3-multiline-graph)?

Comment: if you add a proper answer instead of comment I can accept it