# D3 draw points in a loop

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw the data points of the lines on a line chart, so in a loop through all of lines, I draw the points as below... but not sure why it only draws the points of the first line.

Can someone see what I'm missing here?

```
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        var line = lines[i];

        svg.selectAll('.point')
            .data(line.coordinates)
            .enter()
                 .append("circle")
                     .attr('class', 'point')
                     .attr('stroke', function(d) { console.log(d); return line.color; })
                     .attr('fill', function(d) { return line.color; })
                     .attr("cx", function(d) { return x_scale(d[0]); })
                     .attr("cy", function(d) { return y_scale(d[1]); })
                     .attr("r", 6);

    }
```

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693005/create-points-on-a-d3-multiline-graph

Comment: @Lars, the post you referred, he is drawing points for one line, I have no problem doing that... anyways, I rewrote it as nested selectAll and it worked.

Comment: There's a multiline graph in that question, isn't there? The problem with your approach is that you're using `.enter()`, which will be empty for all but the first calls as the data is matched by the elements you've just added. Using nested selections (as you're doing now) is the D3 way to do this.

Comment: @SeanYang, you should post your solution as the answer to this question.